# JUnit тест поля, которое находится в методе

Tags: java, junit

Задача: написать программу, которая считает деление в столбик Integer'ов
Программа написана.
Первый метод публичный, считает все промежуточные значения остатков и передает во второй уже приватный, и из него получает строку отрисованного решения.
Необходимо на все это написать JUnit тесты.
Можно ли как-то протестировать состояние полученной строки в первом методе из второго?
Первый метод возвращает int(значение деления).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, оно тебе и не нужно. Так же как и нет необходимости тестировать приватные методы. С помощью модульного тестирования ты проверяешь результат, который вернула функция, можешь проверить, какие публичные методы другого класса были вызваны(с помощью библиотеки Mockito).

Но если уж оочень хочется, подумай ещё раз. Если всё ещё хочется - то используй Reflection API